# Redirect IP address to domain name in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect the IP address to the domain name of my website.  This is my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^198\.50\.227\.185 [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.allrealfood.com/$1 [r=301,nc,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I can't figure out how to get this to work.

Comment: Is the htaccess file in the default vhost or the vhost that serves the IP address?

Answer (score 0):

301 (Permanent) Redirect:

```
Redirect 301 / http://mt-example.com/
```

302 (Temporary) Redirect: Point an entire site to a different temporary URL.

```
Redirect 302 / http://mt-example.com/
```

Redirect index.html to a specific subfolder:

```
Redirect /index.html http://example.com/newdirectory/
```

Need to understand more go [here](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F)

Answer (score 0):

Example:

Redirect 302 200.137.132.201/ http://www.example.com/